# How do you create a std::pair containing a std::atomic?

Tags: c++, std, atomic, std-pair, stdatomic

I cannot figure out how to create the following:

```
std::pair<std::atomic<bool>, int>
```

I always invariably get

> /usr/include/c++/5.5.0/bits/stl_pair.h:139:45: error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic::atomic(const std::atomic&)'
>     : first(__x), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }

I've tried

```
std::pair<std::atomic<bool>, int> pair = std::make_pair(true, 1); //doesn't work
std::pair<std::atomic<bool>, int> pair = std::make_pair({true}, 1); //doesn't work
std::pair<std::atomic<bool>, int> pair = std::make_pair(std::atomic<bool>(true), 1); //doesn't work
std::pair<std::atomic<bool>, int> pair = std::make_pair(std::move(std::atomic<bool>(true)), 1); //doesn't work
```

I know std::atomic is non-copyable, so how are you supposed to create it in a pair? Is it just not possible?

Comment: Are you compiling in C++17 mode, or something earlier?

Comment: `{std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(true), std::make_tuple(1)}` for a copy-initialization context

Comment: I'm compiling with c++14

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Do you know how that would work with a std::vector? E.g.
I have a vector of atomics, and I want to emplace one back. I can't do this because of a compiler bug:

std::vector<std::atomic<bool>> atomics;
atomics.emplace_back(true);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
std::pair<std::atomic<bool>, int> p(true, 1);
```

This uses `true` to initialize the atomic first member, without any extraneous copies or moves. In C++17, guaranteed copy elision also allows you to write:

```
auto p = std::pair<std::atomic<bool>, int>(true, 1);
```

Comment: I don't have access to C++17, so I haven't tried the second option, but the first option doesn't work for me unfortunately. I get 
/usr/include/c++/5.5.0/bits/stl_pair.h:139:45: error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<bool>::atomic(const std::atomic<bool>&)'                                                                                                          
  : first(__x), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }

Comment: @RickD That seems like a bug to me. I don't know what your version of `stl_pair.h` looks like, but I would guess that the wrong constructor is being selected. To work around this, you could try the `piecewise_construct` technique mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @RickD It looks like the bug was introduced [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/fe03d4d8ecf57e389d915b5b652d2e8d4ad884eb) and fixed [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/d3c64041b32b6962ad6b2d879231537a477631fb); unfortunately I guess it didn't make it into the 5.5.0 release.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate. I knew this had to be possible, thanks for following up on this. I guess I'll mark this one solved.